# startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() returns false even when access to a file is allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-extensions

I have an iOS app which has an action extension to save documents in it.

The method `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` returns false in some cases even when I am able to access the file.

```
BOOL success = [originalURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];    
if (success) {
    NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:originalURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingForUploading error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) { 
        //My Code
    }
}
```

In the above code, the following is observed

When sharing a file from Apple's Photos App

```
originalURL = file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/49152B46-E719-41A5-A5D5-21EAE6254246/RenderedPhoto/IMG_0026.JPG
```

---

When sharing a file from MS Word App

```
originalURL = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1B0C962F-E7B4-46ED-A9DA-A8213E05A470/tmp/ShareAttachments/%7BC699DC26-37F9-A949-8F69-1F9D6981C4B0%7D/Document.docx
```

---

When sharing a file from Apple's Pages App

```
originalURL = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CDBBDC79-02C7-4ABF-A6B9-F38B6540E2B1/Documents/Document%20(1).pages
```

---

The flag `success` is `true` in the first case (Photos App), but is `false` in the other two (Word & Pages App).

If I remove the success flag check, I am able to access all the three files using the NSFileCoordinator and am able to copy the file into my app.

Therefore, I am not sure why is the method `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` returning false for a scenario where I clearly have the access to copy the file.

The motive is to save the file exported from the file editor app into my iOS app using the action extension.

Comment: I can't help but notice that the URLs from the MS Word App and Pages App have the keyword 'private'. Is this causing the issue? If so, what is the workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I only use `success` to determine either I need to call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` or not inside `NSFileCoordinator` completion handler.

```
BOOL success = [originalURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
[fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:originalURL options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingForUploading error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) { 
    //My Code
    if (success) {
        [originalURL stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    }
}
```

Please note according to Apple's documentation,in case you don't call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`:

> If you fail to relinquish your access to file-system resources when you no longer need them, your app leaks kernel resources. If sufficient kernel resources are leaked, your app loses its ability to add file-system locations to its sandbox, such as via Powerbox or security-scoped bookmarks, until relaunched.

Answer (score 4):

If the file you are trying to access is an external document, which is outside your app's sandbox, then you will need `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` to access the file and it will return true.

If you are accessing documents which are your app's assets or you don't have authorisation, the method will return false.

Refer to this [Apple Doc of UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller). It uses `NSFileCoordinator` to read and write to external documents.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've found out that when I have access to an iCloud folder and I want to process the files, I must process them in the same scope meaning:

```
guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
    
let fileURLs = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
for fileURL in fileURLs { ... }
```

if I am not gonna process the files in the snip code, I will lose access to it.

It seems that when the user selecting a folder there's a stricter enforcement than when the user is manually selecting files.
Regarding the latter, you can actually save the URLs for later usage while folder selection won't work.